# Force git to treat *.ps1 as text file

Tags: git, powershell, bitbucket, diff

Is it possible to treat PowerShell files (*.ps1) as text file and allow to diff, resolve conflicts, etc? For example in BitBucket I don't see changes between commits. Its content is not visible.

How to set it in git configuration?

Comment: It is text file :)

Comment: Should do it without any special settings. What problems are you having exactly?

Comment: Git treats it as binary file. While conflicts I can not resolve conflict, diff etc

Comment: you could always save the code in a `.txt` file and have a `.ps1` just have `gc .\123.txt | iex` in another ps1 file? there should be a git-side solution for this though.

Comment: I think that the problem come from the encoding of the files. Change it to utf8. I think it is because you use the powershell editor that is a pure sheet with that. Prefer vscode with powershell plugin.

Comment: @Mat I refresh title and question. Maybe now it is cleaner

Comment: As far as I know git does not care about name (unless there are attributes set up for a specific paths), only content. There can be 2 issues with content: (1) BOM header, (2) their encoding is in fact utf-16. Which of them do you have in your files?

Comment: Bitbucket isn't Git and `.ps1` is a text file. Git doesn't require text files to be UTF8 encoded either. If you have issues it's either a Bitbucket problem or your own configuration that treats it as binary. What does your *local* diff tool show? Have you tried comparing versions with TortoiseGit ?

Comment: @Philippe You have right with encoding, now it works :) Thanks you, write your comment as aswer. I'll mark it as solution :)

Comment: @Jacek done....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from the encoding of the files (utf7?) .

Change it to utf8.
I think it is because you use the powershell editor that is a pure shit with that. Prefer vscode with powershell plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Like Philippe says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48147892/3329305), the problem comes from the encoding that Powershell ISE uses as default.

You can change the encoding by opening the file in notepad and choosing utf-8 when saving it. Initially after this change, git still can't make a diff since it tries to make a diff between old encoding and new. Changing name of file or making an intermediate commit will make it work however.

After you changed the encoding, you can continue to work with it in Powershell ISE.